# Are my xUnit tests being run sequentially or in parallel?

Tags: .net-core, xunit

When I run my unit tests on the command line, it looks something like this:

```
> dotnet test

Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.2.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:    34, Skipped:     0, Total:    34, Duration: 251 ms
```

Great! However, nothing is printed in the console that answers my question:

**How do I know which tests were constrained to run sequentially and which ones had the potential to be parallelized?**

There are tons of StackOverflow pages about how to parallelize (or not) xUnit tests/collections/assemblies for various frameworks/runners/IDEs. *That's not what I'm asking.* It's hard to know whether I've got it right. I want to know whether my recipe of *attributes* and *config files* and *command line parameters* are all working together as I intended.

Also, I'd rather not have to modify the unit tests with print or log messages.

Comment: Hey buddy, I think you've got enough points to know to go read the docs: https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel and work it out for yourself. TLDR; in a given collection at most one test is executing during a test run.

Comment: @satnhak, I'm not asking how to *specify* that tests should be run in parallel or not. I'm asking how to _verify_ that whatever is running my tests is actually doing what I intended.

Comment: So you don't trust the test runner to do what it purports to do?

Comment: @satnhak I trust the test runner. I don't trust _myself_. How can I double-check that I have read the docs correctly and applied the attributes correctly? The large number of SO questions and answers on this topic confirms to me that it's not easy to get right. And I don't see a way to _confirm_ that I've gotten it right.

Comment: Are you concerned about this because you expect different results from the tests in parallel operation or because you want to have them run in the shortest time possible?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins We are using xUnit as a framework to run integration tests. Some of them cannot be run in parallel. I was looking for a way to confirm that I had configured them correctly. I was hoping for something like a `--test-plan` or `--list-run-order` or something in a log file that would help me double-check my configuration of the tests is what I intended.

Comment: I have a similar situation using XUnit for integration tests. To prevent tests from running in parallel we put them in a ``Collection``. I've never had any problems or symptoms that they might not be running sequentially. Sorry that I can't help with a confirmation output for that.